# How to query soql using 18 character ID?

Tags: apex, soql, query, salesforce-id

I have two IDs that are the same when comparing the 15 character version of each other (the only difference is capitalization). When I attempt to query the data for ID #1 I am receiving the data from ID #2. I tried querying the 18 character version of ID#1 but nothing gets returned? Has anyone ever encountered this issue before?

ID#1 = a1e1E000002KVhJQAW
ID#2 = a1e1E000002KVhjQAG

for example by query is: SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE ActiveDUId__c='a1e1E000002KVhJQAW' and nothing is returned

Comment: where did these Ids come from?  also, records won't be returned if the running user doesn't have record visibility to that record

Comment: If you're doing this from Apex using variables of the `Id` type, the query should not return records of the other id (assuming the capitalization is correct). Internally in Apex, only 18 character ids are used. Like cropredy said, it could be a sharing issue, maybe you can try to make the class `without sharing` to rule that out.

Comment: Looks like you've a text field that keeps the `ID` value. You may want to convert to a relationship field instead or do a `substring to 15 characters` & query for records.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to all of your help. Something was being triggered that was trimming the contact's activeDUId and then updating the contact. As a result, I was unable to make any query's for the 18 character ID. Code now works. Thanks for everyone's answers.